# I have replaced the fan motor and the heating unit in a goodman electric furnace

Tags: furnace

I need an easy wiring diagram for the motor and control board. where do the wires go from the board to the heating unit? I know the heat strip has a plug in but the old strip has a brown wire and the new strip doesn't where does that brown wire go? also the blower wires are confusing to me as I did not remove the motor and I don't know how the new motor is hooked up. I want to make sure I wired up these new units right as I don't want to blow his board with the sequencers and relays. This is a Goodman electric furnace two strip heat strip 9.5 kw. where can I find a schmatic or actual color wire video?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'd need more information, such as a model number and perhaps a photo or two. Or you could Google for the instructions manual...

Comment: Usually, the wiring diagram is stuck to the furnace somewhere :) Can you not find any labeling on it?